# Custom Layout under Editor / Entry

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, grid, focus, editor

I have an Entry/Editor in Xamarin.Forms, and I want a layout to appear underneath it, as long as it is focused.

The layout consists of a Grid with multiple Buttons in it.

I have added the Grid underneath the Editor in my Layout and toggle its visibility based on the IsFocused property of the Editor.
Sadly, when I press one of the Grids buttons, the Editor loses focus and thus the Layout will go invisibile.

**EDIT:**
Another very important point is, that the Grid can overlap other controls, currently this is happening, since im adding both the Editor and the Grid into another Grid as the last children.
I might have to workaround this as well, maybe just put this Grid into an android relative layout and add this layout to the native EditText?

I want it to remain visible after clicking one of the buttons. How should I approach this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I would write EditorRenderer for each platform and there add all buttons, it should fix Focus problem (as you never lost focus :))

Implementation example:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Common
{
    public class CustomEditor : Editor
    {
        public Action<string> ButtonXCallback { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IOS:

```
using Common.iOS;
using Common;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof (CustomEditor), typeof (CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace Common.iOS
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        private UIButton ButtonX { get; set; }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var element = Element as CustomEditor;

            if (Control != null && element != null)
            {
                if (ButtonX == null)
                {
                    ButtonX = new UIButton();
                    ButtonX.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("ico_x.png"), UIControlState.Normal);

                    ButtonX.TouchUpInside += (sender, f) => {
                        var text = Control.Text;

                        if (element.ButtonXCallback != null)
                            element.ButtonXCallback.Invoke(text);
                    };

                    Control.AddSubview(ButtonX);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Droid:

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes;
using Common.Droid;
using Common;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Runtime;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Views;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof (CustomEditor), typeof (CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace Common.Droid
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        private ImageButton ButtonX { get; set; }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
                return;

            if (Element == null)
                return;

            var element = (CustomEditor) Element;
            if (element == null)
                return;

            if (ButtonX == null)
            {
                ButtonX = new ImageButton(Context);
                ButtonX.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ico_x);
                ButtonX.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                ButtonX.Click += (sender, f) =>
                {
                    var text = Control.Text;

                    if (element.ButtonXCallback != null)
                        element.ButtonXCallback.Invoke(text);
                };

                AddView(ButtonX);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, thanks for this example. the only problem is, that i have a (not too complex) grid that holds up to 10 buttons. But it layouts the buttons based on their Text.Length property. Which layout would u take for each platform, to imitate a Xamarin.Forms.Grid?